# What slows my code down? After a while it starts lagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, lag, smoothing

```
var layer=new Array();
var l=0;
function asd(cnt,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6) {
 layer[0]=cnt;
 layer[1]=l1;
 layer[2]=l2;
 layer[3]=l3;
 layer[4]=l4;
 layer[5]=l5;
 layer[6]=l6;
 for (i=0;i<7;i++){
 if(layer[i]!==0) {
    l++;
    }
  }
}
function moves_like_jagger(event,ids) {

var MouseX=event.clientX;
for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
    if (i==0){helper="#k"+ids+" .contain"} else {helper="#k"+ids+" .d"+i};
    amount=(MouseX-$(this).width()/2)*layer[i-1]*2; 
    $(helper).css({"left":amount*50*(i-1),"-moz-transform":"rotateY(" + amount + "deg)"});
}
}
```

Here is my code which rotates and moves images. It executes smoothly for some time but, after moving and rotating these images a lot, it starts lagging and the move is not constant.

I had another, simpler code, to do this a different way which worked fine, but didn't satisfy my needs so I corrected it.

```
var MouseX=event.clientX;

fgs=document.getElementById("fg").style;
bgs=document.getElementById("bg").style;

cts=document.getElementById("contain").style;
fgw=document.getElementById("fg").width/2;
bgw=document.getElementById("bg").width/2;
ctw=document.getElementById("contain").width/2;f
fgs.transform="rotateY("+(x-fgw)*-0.001+"deg)";
fgs.left=(x-fgw)*-0.05+"px";
bgs.transform="rotateY("+(x-bgw)/(-100)+"deg)";
bgs.left=(x-fgw)/-100+"px";
cts.transform="rotateY("+(x-ctw)/-100+"deg)";
cts.left=(x-fgw)/-100+"px";
```

this one would work forever smoothly. Is it the jQuery? or the for ? can someone help me optimizing it too?

Comment: You're introducing an unwanted global (`i`) in the for-loops. Use `var` to prevent this.

Comment: The function that moves the images is named `moves_like_jagger`.  Maybe the code is taking that too literally and trying perform well after decades of smoking, alcohol, and drugs. :P

Comment: Is that all? Will it stop lagging?

Comment: haha that might be the problem, you are right G-Nugget

Comment: I tried it with `var i` but it is still laggy.

Comment: You're not calling me (using @dawe69hun), but I assume you're talking to me when you say "Is that all? Will it stop lagging?" No, it will not stop lagging after inserting `var`. I suspect that jQuery isn't too efficient (it has to interpret that CSS rule over and over again). What's the problem with using the second code snippet? It's far more efficient than using a run-time interpreter.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel sorry for not calling you. I'm new here, I don't know how things are going on in a website like this one. 

so the first code can move only 3 pictures. The oder one can move as many as i want, and I'm using jQuery because it seemed easier and as well I want to select classes etc. Which I can't do with JavaScript (well it is possible but not recommended as far as I'am concerned)

Comment: Is `moves_like_jagger` bound to the `mousemove` event?

Comment: ©BrianHadaway yes it is onmousemove